# Disable workspaces feature in Chrome developer tool?

Tags: google-chrome

Steps to reproduce the problem:

Open the dev tools

Select the "Sources" tab

Open any Javascript file in the Sources tab

After a short (1 to 2 second) delay, the following message appears: "Serving from the file system? Add your files into the workspace"

Dismiss the message by clicking the "X" on the right side

Refresh the page
After a short delay, the message appears again

I don't want to use the workspaces feature, then I should be able to disable these constant, repetitive, annoying messages.  Ideally, there would be a dev tool setting to turn off workspace prompts.

My Chrome version: 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) (Google Chrome is up to date)

Comment: Adding a screenshot will help

Comment: Issue 427810: Stop "Serving from the file system? Add your files into the workspace." notification

Comment: Clicking on X permanently dismisses the infobar, doesn't it? (unless you re-open the devtools in a new incognito session)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this message permanently by clicking on "never show" as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Never show]

This is Developer tools opened in a separate window. I am using latest chrome (v55 as of now), but I have observed that clicking "never show" permanently hides the message in a lot other earlier versions of chrome as well.

<sub><sub>P.S.: I had to blur the code as it belongs to the company I am working for.</sub></sub>

Comment: Lets say that i already clicked `never show` how to undo (let chrome display the message again) this?